# SQL Server 2012 Developer Default Instance not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I just installed SQL Server 2012 developer edition with a default instance of MSSQLSERVER.

The problem I'm facing is when I launch Management Studio and connect using the server name - `(LocalDb)\v11.0` - it works perfectly, but when I try to put in `MSSQLSERVER` as the server name it gives in a Network related or instance specific error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **default instance** on a server is always reachable using

- `.`
- `(local)`
- the machine name, e.g. `YOURPC`

Enter any one of those things in your *Server Name* field when connecting to SQL Server Management Studio (or use any one of those three things in the `server=` or `data source=` elements of your connection string).

But it's definitely **NOT** reachable using `MSSQLSERVER` ...

I don't know where you got that from - but that does **NOT** work - not for any version of SQL Server I'm aware of.

`MSSQLSERVER` is the name of the SQL Server **Windows Service** on your machine, yes - but it **cannot** be used as instance name to connect to!

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the help! could You just give me an example..?

Comment: @Neville: ***what example***?!?!? I listed three ways that you can connect to your default instance .... pick one ....

Comment: I tried the first 2 and i get a Network or instance related error.. only (LocalDb)\v11.0 seems to work!

Comment: @Neville: then you **don't actually** have a full SQL Server 2012 installation with a default instance! What **exactly** did you install? Only the `LocalDB` components???

Comment: Just installed sql server 2012 developer with the default settings available during the installation.. i guess i`ll have to re-install it again.. could You provide me with a useful resource on installing and configuring it from scratch?

Comment: I re-installed SQL 2012 developer once again and all the 3 options you showed up work flawlessly now including (LocalDB\v11.0), i dont know what the problem was initially, but i guess it went off after the re-installation.. Once again man thanks for the help! Appreciate it!